# spring boot can't load environment variables

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I use spring boot 1.3.3.RELEASE at my ubuntu 15.10 and try to configure my app via env properties like this (guided by https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

```
> export SPRING_REDIS_HOST=somehost
> echo $SPRING_REDIS_HOST
somehost
```

My **application.properties** contains:
spring.redis.host=localhost

The problem is that I never get **somehost** in my app.
Any ideas? Did I miss something?

Thanks, George

Comment: And you run your application from the same shell session after setting the variable?

Comment: Ooops! Thank you very much! That was another one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that I set env in another terminal window so java process doesn't see it. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You must set the correct systemPropertiesMode

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html#setSystemPropertiesMode-int-

the default value is fallback. 
"If not being able to resolve a placeholder with the specified properties, a system property will be tried."

Comment: Thank you for sharing but actually problem was in wrong shell session